# ERROR in EPERM: operation not permitted, open

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, clear-cache

I have a react application that starts up fine and has been running for some time now however now when I go to make any edits I am met with the following error....

ERROR in EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ApplicantApp\FrontEnd\build\node_modules.cache.eslintcache'

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 6):

My exact error was

> "ERROR in [eslint] EPERM: operation not permitted, open
> 'Y:\Caido\Dev\CaidoWebFramework\caido_nodejs\node_modules.cache.eslintcache'"

and I solved it like this: In Windows, I right clicked for folder properties on the folder Y:\Caido\Dev\CaidoWebFramework\caido_nodejs\node_modules.cache and unchecked ReadOnly and Hidden.

But I don't really understand what heappened because:

- if I reopen the folder properties again the ReadOnly and Hidden boxes are not changed even if I just saved the same dialog with both checkboxes unchecked.
- the message is about a file that can't be opened and I don't know why these atributtes would affect the behaviour.

Still I'm sure that after I uncheckd these checkboxes for the first time the problem dissapeared.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ERROR in [eslint] EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\CODING\web dev\projects 2.0\portfolio 2.0\frontend_react\node_modules.cache.eslintcache'

For this just go into the path and delete the .eslintcache file, npm will create
a new file without any problem.
this problem is created because of running build commands over and over again and when you try to push git commands and all atleast in my case

but after doing all this it is solved so enjoy ....

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I have another program running and trace file was inaccessible.

Error message:

```
uncaughtException [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open ...\ClientApp\.next\trace'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '...\\ClientApp\\.next\\trace'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to off running file and then you have to use npm run build. i think it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you don't have the permission to edit within the folder. You need to give yourself the permission to edit C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ApplicantApp\FrontEnd. Depending on which Operating System you are using, allowing edit permission might vary. For Mac OS, you need to check the permission of each folder of the whole path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ApplicantApp\FrontEnd\build\node_modules.cache.eslintcache'.

Then, you can remove node_modules folder, and then build it again with npm install (or yarn/Gulp depends on which package manager you are using to build).

I'm not sure if it will fix you problem, but no problem in trying :) Best of luck.